# Android Shell locksettings command from device terminal

Tags: android, shell

Since Oreo there is this fancy locksettings command, that allows you to change the screenlock from adb shell. Now, if I try to run it on my PC everything is working. On my handheld the command will just get an "Aborted." back. Why is that and how can I run the locksettings command from my device?

here is the code for the locksettings command, maybe you can already tell by that:

```
# Script to start "locksettings" on the device
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/locksettings.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.locksettings.LockSettingsCmd "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Download QUTE, a command panel. Start from the first command click and run it. About 10 to 15 commands ran will give enough control over the system. Only because most of the commands are going to fail, unable to run. Then the terminal will suggest you to STACK, for the command code to lock setting. Copy the code and paste it in the terminal. For there your settings should be locked.